# Amend row in a data-frame if it exists in another data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `DfMaster` and `DfError`

`DfMaster` which looks like:

```
     Id           Name Building
0  4653     Jane Smith        A
1  3467    Steve Jones        B
2    34        Kim Lee        F
3  4567     John Evans        A 
4  3643   Kevin Franks        S
5   244  Stella Howard        D
```

and `DfError` looks like

```
     Id           Name Building
0  4567     John Evans        A 
1   244  Stella Howard        D
```

In `DfMaster` I would like to change the `Building` value for a record to `DD` if it appears in the `DfError` data-frame.  So my desired output would be:

```
     Id           Name Building
0  4653     Jane Smith        A
1  3467    Steve Jones        B
2    34        Kim Lee        F
3  4567     John Evans        DD 
4  3643   Kevin Franks        S
5   244  Stella Howard        DD
```

I am trying to use the following:

```
DfMaster.loc[DfError['Id'], 'Building'] = 'DD'
```

however I get an error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([4567,244], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you please change your question to be a [Good Reproducible Pandas Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)? I.e. with machine readable DataFrame denfinition.

Answer (score 1):

try  this using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
errors = list(dfError['id'].unqiue())
dfMaster['Building_id'] = np.where(dfMaster['Building_id'].isin(errors),'DD',dfMaster['Building_id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.loc` expects that you input an index or a Boolean series, not a value from a column.

I believe this should do the trick:

```
DfMaster.loc[DfMaster['Id'].isin(DfError['Id']), 'Building'] = 'DD'
```

Basically, it's telling:
For all rows where Id value is present in `DfError['Id']`, set the value of `'Building'` to `'DD'`.